# I can not put GLFW in CodeBlocks

Tags: linux, cmake, codeblocks, fedora, glfw

I'm trying to build GLFW 3.2.1 on my Linux (Fedora) to use in the CodeBlocks IDE. The steps I'm following are:
1- In the extracted folder, I execute the "**cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .**" Command.
2- In the same folder, I execute the command "**sudo make install**".

I do not know if that's the right method. Now I need to show CodeBlocks where the GLFW is. I can not get past this part. Can someone help me?
(I'm following the tutorial to compile from this site: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html#compile_compile)

Comment: `Now I need to show CodeBlocks where the GLFW is. I can not get past this part.` - Have you tried to use some examples from the net? E.g. this one: http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html. Or, do you have specific problem when follow an usage example?

Comment: I do not understand the example

Comment: I'm new at this area, so I can't do it by myself, could you help me with those things?

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is **badly** suited for tutoring.